# How do I write useful unit tests for a mostly service-oriented app?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

I've used unit tests successfully for a while, but I'm beginning to think they're only useful for classes/methods that actually perform a fair amount of logic - parsers, doing math, complex business logic - all good candidates for testing, no question. I'm really struggling to figure out how to use testing for another class of objects: those which operate mostly via delegation.

Case in point: my current project coordinates a lot of databases and services. Most classes are just collections of service methods, and most methods perform some basic conditional logic, maybe a for-each loop, and then invoke other services.

With objects like this, mocks are really the only viable strategy for testing, so I've dutifully designed mocks for several of them. And I really, really don't like it, for the following reasons:

1. Using mocks to specify expectations for behavior makes things break whenever I change the class implementation, even if it's not the sort of change that ought to make a difference to a unit test. To my mind, unit tests ought to test functionality, not specify "the methods needs to do A, then B, then C, and nothing else, in that order." I like tests because I am free to change things with the confidence that I'll know if something breaks - but mocks just make it a pain in the ass to change anything.
2. Writing the mocks is often more work than writing the classes themselves, if the intended behavior is simple.
3. Because I'm using a completely different implementation of all the services and component objects in my test, in the end, all my tests really verify is the most basic skeleton of the behavior: that "if" and "for" statements still work. Boring. I'm not worried about those.

The core of my application is really how all the pieces work together, so I'm considering 
ditching unit tests altogether (except for places where they're clearly appropriate) and moving to external integration tests instead - harder to set up, coverage of less possible cases, but actually exercise the system as it is mean to be run.

I'm not seeing any cases where using mocks is actually useful.

Thoughts?

Comment: "I'm not seeing any cases where using mocks is actually useful."  That's perhaps too strong a statement.  In your specific (and narrow) case, mocks don't appear to help you.  But the blanket statement on mocks may be a bit to strong for the evidence you've presented.  Are you sure that's your conclusion?

Comment: Well, of course it is scoped to the range of my experience and issues I've encountered. I don't pretend that nobody derives benefit from them. But I am curious for examples, since I've done a lot of development on a lot of different projects and haven't seen any place I'd want to use them. But maybe I'm wrong because I don't understand - if so, I hope someone will challenge me.

Answer (score 3):

If you can write integration tests that are fast and reliable, then I would say go for it.
Use mocks and/or stubs only where necessary to keep your tests that way.

Notice, though, that using mocks is not necessarily as painful as you described:

1. Mocking APIs let you use *loose/non-strict* mocks, which will allow all invocations from the unit under test to its collaborators. Therefore, you don't need to record all invocations, but only those which need to produce some required result for the test, such as a specific return value from a method call.
2. With a good mocking API, you will have to write little test code to specify mocking. In some cases you may get away with a single field declaration, or a single annotation applied to the test class.
3. You can use partial mocking so that only the necessary methods of a service/component class are actually mocked for a given test. And this can be done without specifying said methods in strings.

Answer (score 2):

> To my mind, unit tests ought to test
>   functionality, not specify "the
>   methods needs to do A, then B, then C,
>   and nothing else, in that order."

I agree. Behavior testing with mocks can lead to brittle tests, as you've found. State-based testing with stubs reduces that issue. Fowler weighs in on this in [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).

> Writing the mocks is often more work
>   than writing the classes themselves

For mocks or stubs, consider using an isolation (mocking) framework.

> in the end, all my tests really verify
>   is the most basic skeleton of the
>   behavior: that "if" and "for"
>   statements still work

Branches and loops are logic; I would recommend testing them. There's no need to test getters and setters, one-line pure delegation methods, and so forth, in my opinion.

Integration tests can be extremely valuable for a composite system such as yours. I would recommend them **in addition to** unit tests, rather than instead of them.

You'll definitely want to test the classes underlying your low-level or composing services; that's where you'll see the biggest bang for the buck.

EDIT: Fowler doesn't use the "classical" term the way I think of it (which likely means I'm wrong). When I talk about state-based testing, I mean injecting stubs into the class under test for any dependencies, acting on the class under test, then asserting against the class under test. In the pure case I would not verify anything on the stubs.

Comment: I would not use the terms "state based testing" or "state verification" when talking about method stubbing, as these two things are completely separate and independent.
In the Fowler article, he specificaly describes state verification as "examining the state of the SUT and its collaborators after the method was exercised", which is done through regular JUnit/TestNG asserts, nothing more.

Comment: @Rogerio - I do mean (almost) the same thing as Fowler. Roy Osherove describes it best in the book The Art of Unit Testing: "When using a stub, the assert is performed on the class under test." With mocks, "The test uses the mock object to verify that the test passes." The main difference from Fowler is that in this version of state verification, we are using injected stubs to isolate the SUT from all of its collaborators and **only** examining the state of the SUT (with regular xUnit asserts). http://www.artofunittesting.com/

Comment: You're right, I was reading too much into "state-based testing with stubs". On the other hand, stubs can be seen simply as degenerate mocks which don't perform an automatic assertion. Implementation-wise, the support for mocks and stubs in JMockit Expectations, for example, is mostly shared. The JMockit Annotations API, however, adds a twist to the concept of state verification, by allowing regular asserts to be performed on method call arguments, for calls from the tested unit to its dependencies; or maybe I should call this something else... still thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Writing [Integration Tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) is a viable option here, but should not replace Unit Tests. But since you stated your writing mocks yourself, I suggest using an Isolation Framework (aka Mocking Framework), which I am pretty sure of will be available for your environment too.

Answer (score 0):

Being that you've posted several questions in one I'll answer them one by one.

> How do I write useful unit tests for a mostly service-oriented app?

Do not rely on unit tests for a "mostly service-oriented app"!  Yes I said that in a sentence.  These types of apps are meant to do one thing: integrate services.  It's therefore more pressing that you write integration tests instead of unit tests to very that the integration is working correctly.

> I'm not seeing any cases where using mocks is actually useful.

Mocks can be extremely useful, but I wouldn't use them on controllers.  Controllers should be covered by integration tests. Services *can* be covered by unit tests but it may be wise to have them as separate modules if the amount of testing slows down your project.

> Thoughts?

For me, I tend to think about a few things:

1. What is my application doing?
2. How expensive would it be to perform system level / integration tests?
3. Can I split my application up into modules that can be tested separately?

In the scenario you've provided, I'd say your application *is* an integration of many services.  Therefore, I'd lean heavily on integration tests over unit tests.  I'd bet most of the Mocks you've written have been for http related classes etc.

I'm a bigger fan of integration / system level tests wherever possible for the following reasons:

1. In this day and age of "moving fast", re-factoring the designs of yesterday happens at an ever increasing rate.  Integration tests aren't concerned about implementation details at all so this facilitates rapid change.  Dynamic languages are in full swing making mocks even more dangerous / brittle.  With a static lang, mocks are much safer because your tests won't compile if they're trying to stub out a non existent or misspelled method name.
2. The amount of code written in an integration test is usually 60% less than the amount of code written in a unit test to achieve the same level of coverage so development time is less.  "Yes but it takes longer to run integration tests..." that's where you need to be pragmatic until it actually slows you down to run integration tests.
3. Integration tests catch more bugs.  Mocking is often contrived and removes the developer from the realities of what their changes will do to the application as a whole.  I've allowed way more bugs into production under the "safety net" of 100% unit test coverage than I would have with integration tests.
4. If integration testing is slow for my application then I haven't split it up into separate modules.  This is often an indicator early on that I need to do some extracting into separation.
5. Integration tests do way more for you than reach code coverage, they're also an indicator of performance issues or network problems etc.