# Which testing tools and approaches support 12 factor app

Tags: testing, integration-testing, microservices, acceptance-testing, 12factor

To follow [the 12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) in my (Java) microservice development, I want to construct my testing infrastructure to

1. be conform to the 12 factor app
2. test/push the system under test towards the 12 factor app.

What are good test harnesses (tools and approaches) for this?

---

Details:

To have effective microservices, I want to follow the 12 factor app. To find as many bugs as possible, I want a test harness that is effective for 12 factor microservices -- mine is not.

For instance, when I am developing microservices, I often introduce bugs that are not caught by my unit tests -- cannot be caught since they do not occur in local logic but in plumbing, i.e. only when putting together many pieces (Java code, Javascript code, Helm chart, Docker file, environment variables). Thus I want to strengthen my coarse-grained tests (integration, component and acceptance/end-to-end tests), which leads me to multiple questions related to the 12 factor app, e.g.

1. should I have more coarse-grained tests that run directly in the production environment?
2. Which parts can I mock in my integration and component tests without breaking [dev/prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity)?
3. How can I test that my system under test follow the 12 factor app?

I have found a lot of tools and material for testing (Java) microservices, e.g.

- [The book Testing Java Microservices](https://www.manning.com/books/testing-java-microservices)
- https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/
- [How do I write useful unit tests for a mostly service-oriented app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567941/how-do-i-write-useful-unit-tests-for-a-mostly-service-oriented-app)
- http://arquillian.org/
- https://github.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly-java
- https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured
- https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm
- https://www.testcontainers.org/

Unfortunately, none of them give advice on the 12 factor app -- it isn't even mentioned. Hence any advice on testing approaches that support the 12 factor app is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the problem is the "shitty" difference between unit-tests and integration-tests.

There are in-betweens, imhO you should design your tests to check the complete service-functionality as it is defined by the contract, by simulating,mocking the services it consumes and calling it at the interfaces it provides. To do that you need a framework like springunit, cdi-unit, ioc-unit or arquillian.

Testing only single (or a few) classes of the service and mocking the rest exposes too much internals of the code to the testcode which prevents refactoring and also often leads to tests which just copy the businesslogic somewhat so they don't really test the functionality.